# VS Code Extension Settings

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have created a working VS Code extension. The extension allows someone teaching code to provide students with real-time access to the teacher's code.

I want to add one more feature to the extension to allow the teacher to connect the VS Code extension to an account form a separate web application. The teacher would login to their account on the web application, generate a token, and place that token in the VS Code extension settings.

I have spent hours looking for documentation or examples on how to add settings to a VS Code extension but can't find anything.

Is this possible? Does anyone know how to do this? Or aware of any good documentation/examples?

Answer (score 2):

Yes a little tricky as what you are looking for are `configurations` - which can be created by an extension and set by a user.

[Configuration docs (settings)](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/contribution-points#contributes.configuration)

> Contribute configuration keys that will be exposed to the user. The
> user will be able to set these configuration options as User Settings
> or as Workspace Settings, either by using the Settings editor or by
> editing the JSON settings file directly.

There are examples and extensive docs at that link above.

Here is sample code from an extension I wrote which creates 2 settings:

```
 "configuration": [
   {
    "title": "Find and Transform",
    "properties": {
     "find-and-transform.enableContextMenus": {
      "type": "boolean",
      "scope": "machine",
      "default": true,
      "markdownDescription": "Show `Search in this File`, `Search in this Folder` and `Search in the Results Files` in the context menus."
     },
     "find-and-transform.enableWarningDialog": {
      "type": "boolean",
      "scope": "machine",
      "default": true,
      "markdownDescription": "Enable a warning dialog if there are bad argument keys or values in settings and keybindings."
     }
    }
   }
  ]
```

Comment: I think he is looking for the `update` method of the configuration object

Comment: Awesome thanks! I will try this link out!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you looking for that extension :
https://code.visualstudio.com/learn/collaboration/live-share,
it acts like google docs, with live share.

Comment: Not quite what I was looking for. I want students to be able to follow along without requiring a specific IDE or plugin. But thanks!